# more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have got problem with follow sql query. It is "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression in postgresql". How can I fix it?

```
SELECT ST_AsText( ST_Intersection(
            ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(100 100, 200 200, 500 400)'))), 
            (select my_linestrings FROM test1dd))
    );
```

Which `select my_linestrings FROM test1dd` is include about 10 rows.

I wanna to get intersection between all row from my_linestrings and the one I just made (ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(100 100, 200 200, 500 400)'))

Comment: I wanna to get intersection between all row from my_linestrings and the one I just made (ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(100 100, 200 200, 500 400)'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a subquery in a `select` statement, it must only return a single record.  Perhaps you're looking for something like this instead:

```
SELECT ST_AsText( 
          ST_Intersection(
              ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(100 100, 200 200, 500 400)'), my_linestrings
          )
       )
FROM test1dd
```

Depending on the data type of `my_linestrings`, you may need to use `ST_GeomFromText` around it as well.